# Preview different md file from subfolder in repo root instead of README file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a folder called `Docs` in the repo which has multiple `.md` files. I want to preview a particular `.md` file in the repo root instead of `readme.md`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same here. It's kind of unbelievable that you need to actually rename each file `README.md` and commit it if you want to see it.